# No audio, or just pops and whispers

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-juarez-gunslinger

When I start Call of Juarez there is one big "pop" and then I lose the audio. Sometimes I hear a faint something in my headphones, but mostly nothing. The game works fine otherwise. What's wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: can you hear anything else through the headphones, if not then you busted them